# Why a static Bootstrap page does not be loaded?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, preloader

I've got a html page using Bootstrap that will not load. The pre-loader just sits there and continuously acts like its loading, but it WILL NOT load the page content. What would cause this sort of behavior? I do not have the site on a live server yet but I have checked the console and there's no errors or anything so I don't understand why this would be happening considering every other page in the site works just fine.

Comment: Showing the code might help... How are you trying to "load" the page? Are you just clicking on a `.html` file? But please show the code.

Comment: Usual culprit is a JS error that is killing down the line functionality. BUT if you say there are no console errors, have you checked the page and seen if your content is actually there and loaded but you somehow missed the visibility switch between the preloader and content? If not, can you debug the js steps when loading the data? Kinda need more to go on here than what you have given.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is static then please check that the necessary scripst and css file paths given correctly as given below

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!-- Optional theme -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Something....
    </body>
    </html>
```